# error: can't find symbol even though its a public variable?

Tags: java

I'm getting many errors such as the one below and I'm stumped as to why as I have made sure not to access said private variable directly

```
symbol:   method GetP()
location: class LineSegment
FastCollinearPoints.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
           Point big = nonFinishedSegments.get(i).GetQ()
```

here is the relevant class that the unfound symbol is declared

```
public class LineSegment {
    private Point p;   // one endpoint of this line segment
    private Point q;   // the other endpoint of this line segment

    public Point GetQ(){
        return this.q;
    }
    public Point GetP(){
        return this.p;
    }


    public LineSegment(Point p, Point q) {
        if (p == null || q == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("argument is null");
        }
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }
```

and here is the part of the other script where the error is found (all GetQ and GetP draws an error)

```
 public FastCollinearPoints(Point[] points) {
         final ArrayList<LineSegment> nonFinishedSegments = new ArrayList<LineSegment>();

        if (checkForNullPoints(points) || checkForDuplicates(points)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception");
        }
        Point[] copy = points.clone();
        Arrays.sort(copy);
        for(int i = 0; i < copy.length-1; i++){
            nonFinishedSegments.add( new LineSegment(copy[i],copy[i+1]));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nonFinishedSegments.size(); i ++){
             final ArrayList<LineSegment> sameAngle = new ArrayList<>();
             Point small = nonFinishedSegments.get(i).GetP();
             Point big = nonFinishedSegments.get(i).GetQ();
             int size = 2;

             double angle = nonFinishedSegments.get(i).GetP().slopeTo(nonFinishedSegments.get(i).GetQ());
            for (LineSegment nonFinishedSegment : nonFinishedSegments) {
                if (nonFinishedSegment.GetP().slopeTo(nonFinishedSegment.GetQ()) == angle) {
                    sameAngle.add(nonFinishedSegment);
                }
            }
            for (LineSegment lineSegment : sameAngle) {
                if (lineSegment.GetP() == big) {
                    big = lineSegment.GetQ();
                    size++;
                    size++;

                }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, but I do see that you have not added a return type for the method FastCollinearPoints. 
Assuming you deliberately did it, try refreshing/rebuilding your project. Also I would suggest following the naming conventions for methods, such as, GetP() should be getP().

Comment: I'm still getting the error, I've compiled it multiple times and it still isn't working but thanks for the tip on the naming conventions.

Comment: @gagarwa -- Would a debugger help if the code doesn't compile?  
OP -- How are you building the application? Freakish compile-time errors like this sometimes arise when there are old versions of compiled classes lurking around in a build environment.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because the problem cannot be determined from the code that you have provided.  (One possibility is that `LineSegment` class you are using in `FastCollinearPoints` is a different class to the one that you showed us.  Check the imports, project configs and your build methodology.)

Comment: @Kevin Boone You got me.  I only focused on the code, and missed this important point!